# Python web scraper, json output, framework, server

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to create python web scraper to get and format some data for me and output it in json format so that other web pages can access it. I want to put this service on some of the free python hosts out there.

Because this is my first python project I have some questions.

1. Should I use any of the python web frameworks for this? As I am not really concern about security (I will have only couple of pages with on input) I thought to leave it just as a script.
2. I do need some small database. What library can you suggest for this?
3. Are there cron jobs on python web servers?
4. Do free servers allow site scrapping every X minutes?
5. I have python 2.7 as default in my linux. Can/ Should I work with it or should I try to get the new version up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, it makes life easier. But you have to check what framework can be used on free server. Sometimes you can't install own modules.
2. `sqlite` doesn't need installation. `mysql` and `postgres` mostly are preinstalled on servers but you have to check it.
3. mostly yes but you have to check it.
4. some servers may not allow scraping any sites but you have to check it.
5. use version which is installed on server so you have to check it.

Some free servers run page 18 hours a day and freezes page on 6 hours a day - but you have to check it.